WebRTC flow - not triggering answer
I am creating a test web rtc video call app with vanilla js using vite. I am handling the rtc connection flow as this. First globally I initialize a RTCPeerConnection with iceservers. Then I have a button to start the cam and I handle adding local and remote streams to PC.
Then I have a create Offer button, in that button. Then I create offer and set as local description and send the offer via web sockets.
I am listening to web sockets messages. I handle candidates, offers, and answers. In offers when web sockets receives an offer I create a new RTCSessionDescription and then set it as remote description. And in offer I am creating an answer with pc.createAnswer() and set it as pc.setLocalDescription and then send the answer. And in answer I create a new RTCSessionDescription and then set it as remote description. And when I receive a candidate create new RTCIceCandidate add that candidate to PC using addIceCandidate. that's how I handle signaling.
And also I listen for pc.onicecandidate event and then I send the candidate via web sockets
This is the code
const servers = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'],
    },
  ],
  iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
};

// Global State
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
let localStream = null;
let remoteStream = null;


const webcamButton = document.getElementById('webcamButton');
const webcamVideo = document.getElementById('webcamVideo');
const callButton = document.getElementById('callButton');
const answerButton = document.getElementById('answerButton');
const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/" + 123);

const generateRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

socket.onopen = () => {
  console.log('connected to socket');

  socket.send(JSON.stringify({
    type: 'join',
    userId: generateRandomNumber(0, 100)
  }));
}

Signaling with sockets
socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (data.type === 'offer') {
    console.log('has offer', data);
    const offerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data)
    pc.setRemoteDescription(offerDescription)

    const answerDescription = pc.createAnswer()
    pc.setLocalDescription(answerDescription)

    const answer = {
      type: answerDescription.type,
      sdp: answerDescription.sdp,
    };

    socket.send(JSON.stringify(answer));

  } else if (data.type === 'answer') {
    console.log('has answer', data);
    if (!pc.currentRemoteDescription) {
      const answerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data)
      pc.setRemoteDescription(answerDescription)
    }

  } else if (data.type === 'candidate') {
    console.log('has candidate', data);
    const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate)
    if (candidate) pc.addIceCandidate(candidate)
  }
}

Getting feed from camera
webcamButton.onclick = async () => {

  localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
  remoteStream = new MediaStream();

  // Push tracks from local stream to peer connection
  localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    pc.addTrack(track, localStream);
  });

  // Pull tracks from remote stream, add to video stream
  pc.ontrack = (event) => {
    event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      remoteStream.addTrack(track);
    });
  };

  webcamVideo.srcObject = localStream;
  remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;

};

// 2. Create an offer
callButton.onclick = async () => {
  console.log('in call button func');


  // Create offer
  const offerDescription = await pc.createOffer();
  await pc.setLocalDescription(offerDescription);

  const offer = {
    sdp: offerDescription.sdp,
    type: offerDescription.type,
  };

  socket.send(JSON.stringify(offer))
};

pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
  if (event.candidate) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
      type: 'candidate',
      candidate: event.candidate,
    }));
  }
};

Is my web rtc flow correct ? And it does not seems like even if I send the offer, it is not creating an answer because I don't see 'has answer' in the console.
I want to answer the call automatically when the 2nd user join the room, even if I create a separate function to answer the call it's confusing to me where should I call the function.
